# using javascript to disable link in php script

Tags: php, javascript

Hello I am trying to disable a link in my PHP script using a JS function. I am not sure why is its not working. Any input appreciated..

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript">

function disable() 
{   document.getElementById("perfumes_web_link").innerHTML='<a href="javascript: void(0)"><http://www.google.com" rel="external"">Perfumes</a>';    
}

function enable() 
{       document.getElementById("perfumes_web_link").innerHTML='<a href="http://www.google.com" rel="external"">Perfumes<\/a>';

}       
</script>

</head>

<?php

$disable_link = 0 ;

echo '<h1>JavaScript to disable link if  set to zero</h1>';
echo '<li><span id="perfumes_web_link"></span><br>'."\n";
echo '<span class="perfumes_browser"><small>(Internet Explorer v6 or higher req.)    < /small></span></li>';

if ($disable_link = 1)
{echo '<script type="text/javascript">disable();</script>';
}
elseif ($disable_link = 0) 
{
echo '<script type="text/javascript">enable();</script>';
}

?>
</html>
```

So what am i doing wrong? Should i use if/else statement in the JS function itself or should i use true/false instead of 0 and 1.

Should i use something else like jQuery or Ajax..

Thanks

Comment: Can't see that you're switching this anywhere but in the PHP so why don't you just output the link or not link instead of putting JS in there to do it on the client side?

Comment: thats not the way of joining javascript and pHP

Comment: its the = / == issue as Sudhir answered right. But can you explain your syntax here? `<a href="javascript: void(0)"><http://www.google.com" rel="external"">Perfumes</a>`

Comment: @godesign The idea of using the void() was to disable the link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since you are comparing, use `==` instead of `=`,
like, change

```
if ($disable_link = 1)
```

to

```
if ($disable_link == 1)
```

OR you can do:

```
if ($disable_link == 1) {
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">disable();</script>';
}
else {
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">enable();</script>';
}
```

If you mean to open the link in new window, use `target="_blank"` instead of `rel="external"`, like:
change

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" rel="external"">Perfumes<\/a>
```

to

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Perfumes</a>
```

Comment: @ricardo, thats fine, i was refering to the anchor link, see my added answer

Comment: I understood that but for disabling the link like greying it out i am using the javascript:void(0) ..is nit this a irght method to do it?

Comment: @ricardo yes javascript:void(0) can be used to disable the link, as void operator evaluates the given expression and then returns undefined. So thats fine..

Comment: Thanks..it did work but while the void(0) works it does not grey out the color of the hyperlink

Comment: @ricardo void(0) does not do that, you could add some css class for gray'ed out links and add that class in you anchor link for disabled links